# What version of tSQLt (Database Test Framework) have I installed?

Tags: sql, tsqlt

Is there any way I can find the version number of [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org) that is installed on a database?

Please note that tSQLt is a test framework for SQL server, not T-SQL. (don't vote to close as duplicate of something unrelated, please.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code, it looks like there is an info function which returns the version number.
Try

```
SELECT * FROM tSQLt.Info()
```

Comment: So long as the version is >= v1.0.4414.31717 (http://tsqlt.org/432/tsqlt-v1-0-4413-31717-release-notes/)

Comment: @EdHarper That will teach me to not just look at the stored procs, but also in the functions. :)

Comment: @Paddy That is not correct. The `info()` function was been in tSQLt (at least) since V1.0.4351.28410. Prior to v1.0.4414.31717 it only reported script version, not CLR version.

Comment: @steenhulthin Ah ok, I just found that release note and from the language assumed they were both new features of that version.